# Get Home/office address from google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-signin

I have an map based android app and am providing functionality to login using gmail account. Now, Google maps on the device has saved home and office address of the user. Is it possible to get this data without user having to input it?

Answer (score 0):

You can geocode the addresses with **[Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)**.

Depending of what you want, you can get an XML or JSON response by calling

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ADRESS HERE
```

Where all the spaces of the address must be replaced by `+`.
The data you want is located in `geometry->location`.

Comment: I need Home and office address saved on device on an android phone.

Comment: @Mitech did you find the way to get the address? I am also looking for the same. Or let me know if it's not possible.